# Tensorflow RNN number prediction in a sequence

Tags: python, windows, csv, tensorflow

I have a sequence of fault code numbers that I have reformatted and set into batches of 4, 315 batched lists, to be precise. I followed the tensorflow [RUN tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/recurrent#the_model) in deciding to do so. These batches of 4 are in a separate .csv file.

I want to understand and write the tensorflow code for predicting the next number in the sequence. I've looked everywhere and I don't really understand how to do it although it seemed quite simple to begin with!

How do I know how many hidden layers to use? How do I even write the `csv` batches to the code? Can you write an example for me using an imported `csv` and tensorflow?

```
[726321,3489137,12310,213219]

[134134,324234,412431,443525]
```

There will be 315 rows of this format in a `.csv`

Going on the basis of the article:

I believe I have 1 feature- the fault code number

- My batch size is 315
- My number of batches is 4
- Time steps is 4

Comment: Please note that the [tag:batch-file] tag is a Windows script and has nothing to do with [tag:tensorflow], please reomve the tag by editing it.